# nodejs restler module post test call EMPTY body?

Tags: testing, node.js

I am writing some tests for my nodejs app. Tests work ok, the only problem I'm having (using restler) is that when I test a post request the body sent in the request is always empty.

This is what I'm doing:

```
rest.post('http://localhost:3000/api/testpost1', {
    name : "my name"
}).on('complete', function(data,res) {
    console.log("status code",res.statusCode)
});
```

The body in the req.body on the server is always equal to: {}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm going to respond to my own question: rest.post('http://localhost:3000/api/testpost1', {
        data: { "name" : "zzzz" }
    }).on('complete', function(data,res) {
        console.log("status code",res.statusCode)
    });
The post body that I need to send has to be enclosed in "data"....

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
rest.post('http://localhost:3000/api/testpost1', {
    data: {name : "my name"}
}).on('complete', function(data,res) {
    console.log("status code",res.statusCode)
});
```